# Resolving borrowed value issue

Tags: rust

I have the following simple code. I am not able to figure out how to resolve the error "borrowed value does not live long enough".

```
fn main() {
    let mut saved_message: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let mut tmp: String = String::from("line_num ");
        tmp.push_str(&i.to_string());
        saved_message.push(&tmp);
    }
}
```

```
   Compiling rust_test v0.1.0 (C:\workspace\rust_test)
error[E0597]: `tmp` does not live long enough
 --> src\lib.rs:6:28
  |
6 |         saved_message.push(&tmp);
  |         -------------------^^^^-
  |         |                  |
  |         |                  borrowed value does not live long enough
  |         borrow later used here
7 |     }
  |     - `tmp` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `rust_test` due to previous error
```

Comment: `tmp` is dropped on the next loop iteration.  That memory does not exist anymore.  You need a `Vec<String>`

Answer (score 3):

Error comes from this line:

```rust
    let mut saved_message: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
```

Here, you defined a vector of references to string slices.

Since you are storing references instead of the whole string, every reference that is stored in the vector, should outlive the vector itself. But this is not the case with your code as each `tmp` value in your for loop gets droped at the end of the loop (reference is no longer valid) and thus, pushing it to a vector that would outlive the for loop is not safe.

workarounds:
Create a vector of `String` instead of `&str`

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut saved_message: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let mut tmp: String = String::from("line_num ");
        tmp.push_str(&i.to_string());
        saved_message.push(tmp);
    }
}
```

Notice the vector type hint which is now `Vec<String>` instead of `Vec<&str>`.
Note that now you should push `tmp` instead of `&tmp` in the last line.
You can also trust the compiler to guess the type for you and remove the whole type hint:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut saved_message = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let mut tmp = String::from("line_num ");
        tmp.push_str(&i.to_string());
        saved_message.push(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arshia Akhavan, Thanks so much.